# AWS Simple AD create Directory User for AWS WorkSpaces via CLI or CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces, aws-directory-services

When using AWS WorkSpaces with Simple AD, when we want to provision a new WorkSpace for a new User, the AWS WorkSpace console allows us to add a new User through the UI and create the WorkSpace to associate with the new User.  There is [CloudFormation support for creating a WorkSpace instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-workspaces-workspace.html#cfn-workspaces-workspace-username)  which includes the required property of `UserName`.  We are looking for a way to programmatically create the underlying User in the Simple AD Directory - either through CloudFormation or from the CLI, in concert with creating the WorkSpace instance.  I checked the CloudFormation docs and the AWS CLI docs and can't seem to find anything related to User creation.  However, since the User creation can be done with the AWS Management Console, I'm under the assumption that there must be a CLI/SDK call that we can hook into to do this action.

Inspecting the network tab when creating a user in the console, I can see the API call that get made "https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/service?operation=createDirectoryUser" but don't see a corresponding action in the [CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workspaces/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per AWS Support - this functionality is currently NOT exposed via the CLI/ service API.  They indicated that "it will be considered for potential implementation in future updates."